# Divergence Theorem? Generalization?

Tags: divergence-operator

Say $F=(F_1(x),F_2(x),F_3(x))$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$.

The standard divergence theorem states:
$\int\int F\cdot n dS=\int\int\int\nabla\cdot F dV$.

Then, if $G=(G_1(x),G_2(x),G_3(x))$, what can we say about $\int\int (F\cdot n)GdS$?

Or, if you prefer, you can think of $G$ as a scalar valued function of $x$.

Comment: I'm inclined to think that, if $G$ is 'sufficiently nice', then you could conclude that $\int\int(F\cdot n)GdS=\int\int\int\nabla\cdot FGdV$. But what sufficiently nice would be I am not sure, if $G$ is a scalar *constant*, then the result I gave follows by linearity of the (multiple) integral.

Comment: @JustinBenfield: What you've written holds *only* when $G$ is a constant function, whether we interpret the RHS as $(\nabla\cdot F)G$ or $\nabla\cdot(FG)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case of a scalar function $\phi$ (you can apply this to each component of your $G$ if you wish). Then, by the Divergence Theorem, 
$$\iint (\phi F)\cdot n\,dS = \iiint \nabla\cdot(\phi F)\,dV = \iiint \big(\phi\,\nabla\cdot F+\nabla\phi\cdot F\big)\,dV.$$

Comment: Thank you! Didn't realize it was just a simple application of the product rule.